# Is there any "Hello World" example type basic tutorial for heuristics or Meta Heuristics or optimization techniques

Tags: python, optimization, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I am trying hard but still i have not found a very basic tutorial from where i can start with Meta heuristics and optimization problems. I have seen many books but they are full of Maths. I know that eventually i have to do that but if al least i have one simple example running before me , then i can get some confidence rather than reading books and have nothing practical in front of me.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial where someone has described a small problem and then he discusses its solution with heuristics so that i know how practically it is applied.

`I don't want anyone to write code for me but any tutorial out there which can help me in writing code for those heuristics`

If its done in any programming language then its good but otherwise I will be happy to see how the algorithms solves particular problem.

I know there are many algorithms but i don't know where to start so any optimization algorithm will be fine as long as i understand how it works so then i can proceed further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's **a visual explanation** of heuristic and metaheuristic algorithms [in this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/ge0ffrey/drools-planner-webinar-20110615-drools-planner-optimizes-automated-planning/28).

For example:

[image]